# How do I use concepts in if-constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20, if-constexpr

How does one use concepts in `if constexpr`?

Given the example below, what would one give to `if constexpr` to return 1 in case `T` meets the requirements of `integral` and else 0?

```
template<typename T>
concept integral = std::is_integral_v<T>;

struct X{};

template<typename T>
constexpr auto a () {
    if constexpr (/* T is integral */) {
        return 1;
    } 
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main () {
    return a<X>();
}
```

Comment: This particular function can be simplified to `return integral<T>;`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is sufficient to do:

```
if constexpr ( integral<T> )
```

since `integral<T>` is already testable as `bool`

Comment: Is this still valid in the latest draft of the Standard? Or do we need `requires integral<T>` instead?

Answer (score 31):

[Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) are named **boolean** predicates on template parameters, evaluated at **compile time**.

In a [constexpr `if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) statement, the value of the condition must be a contextually converted constant expression of type **`bool`**.

So in this case, usage is simple:

```
if constexpr ( integral<T> )
```

Comment: Is this still valid in the latest draft of the Standard? Or do we need `requires integral<T>` instead?